# Distance between straight lines

Tags: spotfire

I work in the oil & gas industry and I'm seeking advice about how to calculate the minimum distance between a set of wells (the wells are drawn as straight lines on a map). My goal is for each individual well to have a unique "spacing" value (measured in feet) which is basically the straight-line horizontal distance to the closest wellbore on a map. Below is a simple example of what I'm trying to accomplish (assume the pipe | symbol is a wellbore and the dashes are the distance between the wells)

|--|---|-|

In the drawing above we have 4 wells. The 1st well (starting from the far left) would have a spacing value of 2 (since there are 2 dashes to the closest well), the 2nd well would also have a value of 2 (since the closest well is the one to the far left which is two spaces away), the 3rd well would have a value of 1, and the 4th well would have a value of 1.

Now imagine that I have hundreds of these wells (each with latitude/longitude points that describe the start & end points of each well)  and I have them all mapped in TIBCO Spotfire (scattered across Texas). Do you guys know if it would even be possible to automate a calculation like the above? I would also like to build in a rule that says the max distance between wells is 2640 ft (half of a mile).

Any ideas are appreciated!

Comment: I'm leaving this as a comment because I don't have a detailed solution. I would calculate this either outside of Spotfire or with TERR, which would require R programming knowledge. My basic idea would be to calculate the distance matrix which would contain all pairwise distances, and then replace all over 2640. My problem is that I'm not familiar with how to calculate distance based on lat, lon. Hope this gives you some idea.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be able to do this without any R or iron python.

Within Spotfire, you can calculate the distance in miles between 2 points using the formula below (substitute 6371 for 3958.756 to get the answer in kilometres).

```
GreatCircleDistance([Lat 1],[Lon 1],[Lat 2],[Lon 2]) * 3958.756
```

For your use case, you could cross join your table of locations, so that you have a row for every possible location combination, then calculate the distance between them using the formula above. After that, it should be pretty straight forward to find each wells closest pair.